# Why does postfix operator++ have higher precedence than prefix operator++?

Tags: c++, increment, operator-precedence, prefix-operator, postfix-operator

Defined this way, we can do neither `++x++` nor `++x--`. But on the other hand, both `(++x)++` and `(++x)--` are useful expressions: `(++x)++` increments `x` by two and returns the value "in the middle", while `(++x)--` is essentially equivalent to `x+1` but completely avoids having to call `operator+`, which can be quite useful sometimes.

So why is the precedence not defined to have `++x++` automatically expand to `(++x)++` rather than `++(x++)`? Is there some hidden meaning to the latter which I don't understand, or is it just to keep the precedence a simple list with all prefix operators making up one single level?

**EDIT** Ok, I didn't explicitly say it, but: of course I meant `x` to be user-defined type. For built-in types, `(x+=2)-1` is of course better than `(++x)++`, and `x+1` is a *lot* better than `(++x)--`. The situation that I have in mind is an iterator to a rather complicated type of semi-associative container, where operators `+=` and `+` (being designed for random access) have to rebuild a cache in order to work efficiently for general requests, and are therefore an order of magnitude slower than `++`. But of course I can modify them to always check first if the argument is a very small integer, and in that case just call `operator++` repeatedly instead of doing the random-access procedure. That should work fine here, though I could imagine I might at some point have a situation in which I want `operator+=` to always go the random-access way, regardless of how small numbers I present it.

---

So... for me, I would conclude the answer to be:

> the advantage of having a simple and well-memorizeable precedence list in which *all* postfix operators come before *any* of the prefix operators is sufficient to tolerate the minor drawback of always having to use parentheses to compose pre- and postfix operators `++`/`--`, as this composition is used very seldom.

The simpler "C does it this way", while it seems likely to be the *real* reason, is far less satisfying in to me, because since `++x++` was not allowed *at all* in C it would have been possible to redefine this very composition without damaging any existing code.

Anyway, I will go on using `(++x)--`, as the parentheses really do not hurt so much.

Comment: even if these examples weren't ub there would be little utility because of the great scope for confusion

Comment: Does the original C spec have anything to say on how those operators are grouped?

Comment: If so, my guess would be it just made the grammar easier to write.

Comment: On a sidenote, every postfix operator has higher precedence than every prefix operator. I find this uniform syntax rule quite useful when deciphering complicated C declarators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ standard just kept the C rules and obviously those weren't fixed considering operator overloading and idioms yet be invented in a yet to be invented language.

Looking at what is available in [D.M. Ritchie Home Page](http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/dmr/), on see that this precedence is already present in B (*Unary operators are bound right to left. Thus `-!x++` is bound `-(!(x++))`* in *Users' Reference to B*) and I didn't see increment operators in BCPL.

Answer (score 6):

> `(++x)++` increments `x` by two and returns the value "in the middle"

Why not `(x += 2) - 1` or `(++x, x++)`? Both seem to be clearer. For scalars, both are well-defined also in C++03, as opposed to your proposed expression.

---

> `(++x)--` is essentially equivalent to `x+1` but completely avoids having to call `operator+`, which can be quite useful sometimes.

That's an arbitrary statement without any explanation. So I'm going to throw into the pool:

> `x+1` is essentially equivalent to `(++x)--` but completely avoids having to call `operator++` and `operator--` which can be useful sometimes.

---

> So why is the precedence not defined to have ++x++ automatically expand to (++x)++ rather than ++(x++)

Just to make such arcane corner cases not error out? No way. Can you please recite `man operator` for me? If you cannot do that, better not try and write `++x++` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Both `(++x)++` and `(++x)--` invoke [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points) [assuming x to be a primitive type]. For user defined type the scenario [would be different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638364/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points-reloaded). However it is not generally recommended to use such *confusing expressions* in your code.

As far as the precendence is concerned [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218026/why-does-x-have-higher-precedence-than-x/2218311#2218311) explains why post increment has higher precedence than pre increment.

Comment: Since the type of `x` was not specified in the question, neither of these necessarily yields undefined behavior.

Comment: BTW, I read the Eric's post from the link you posted, and it explains nothing. Also the question in that link is tagged with `C#`. C# is not same as C++. I don't understand the relevance of Eric's post here.

Comment: @Nawaz : His reason seems appropriate from the point of view of C++ as well.

Comment: @Nawaz : So what did the standardization committee think?

Comment: The honest answer is : I don't know.